# Simplify if-else expression

Tags: c#

I am trying to manage a 3-result dialog, in `if ... else`, but I find it hard to use. This is my code:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) == DialogResult.Yes) {
   MessageBox.Show("Why?!", "", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
   Application.Restart();
} else if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) == DialogResult.No) {
    if (MessageBox.Show("OK ^_^! Good Luck!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK) 
        Application.Restart();
} else {
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel?", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK) {
        MessageBox.Show("Ok! Good Luck!");
        Application.Restart();
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!");
        Application.Restart();
    }
}
```

Whenever I run it, if I press "No" or "Cancel", it opens a new dialog. How can I avoid that?

Comment: You should indent your code with (at least) four spaces for it to format correctly.

Comment: Seems like a codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Assign the result of MessageBox.Show to a variable and check this variable in the if statements.

Comment: You could very easily find the answer to this using the debugger.

Comment: 1. You are not checking the return code of `MessageBox.Show("Why?!", "", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);`. 2. The `if` next to `"OK ^_^! Good Luck!"` does not use braces (`{`, `}`).

Comment: Your users are going to hate you.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you want to achieve. Do you really want to open a sequence of different dialogs or just one? If the former, what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann omitting the curly brackets around single-statement `if` statements is a coding style.  the `if` statement that you mentioned will still compile (unless the syntax is faulty inside the parentheses).

Comment: @Tau Yes of course. Yet in this case you would probably agree, that braces are helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You should first get the `DialogResult` and then use it in the `if-else` statement:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //Code if Ok
}
else if(result == DialogResult.No)
{
    //Code if No
}
else
{
    //Code if Cancel
}
```

This way the `MessageBox` will open only once

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: How so? As per OP's question: `Whenever I run it, if I press "No" or "Cancel", it opens a new dialog. How can I avoid that?`

Comment: It does. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MaxGrip Glad this helped you. plz accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

Your first `if` statement is checking for a result of `Yes`:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

If the user selects `No` or `Cancel`, you move on to the next `if` statement which produces another `MessageBox`:

```
else if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) == DialogResult.No) {
```

Finally, if the user selects 'Cancel', you get yet another `MessageBox`:

```
else {
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel?", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK) 
     //Other code here...
     }
```

This is why you see multiple `MessageBox` instances.

So, you should only show one box, then work with the result. However, the code suggests that additional information must be gathered on certain instances:

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
switch(result)
{
    case DialogResult.Yes:
        //Another box pops up to ask the user why
        MessageBox.Show("Why?!", "", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
        Application.Restart();
        break;
    case DialogResult.No:
        //Informational box
        MessageBox.Show("OK ^_^! Good Luck!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        Application.Restart();
    default:
        //Assume Cancel to be the default behavior, 
        //Pick any value to be the default. It's up to you.
        //Make sure they really, REALLY want to cancel
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel?", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ok! Good Luck!");
            Application.Restart();
        } 
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!");
            Application.Restart();
        }
}
```

I don't think your code should be calling `Application.Restart` at the `false` branch of the `Cancel` alternative, but the logic is up to you.

As others have pointed out, please try to properly indent/format your code. It will make it easier for you and others to understand.